# How to display youtube video with advertisement and skip button functionality?

Tags: asp.net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I succeed in displaying a youtube video on my asp.net web application page but I want to display the advertisement also present in that same video. Though the video which i displayed on web application page contains advertisement then also it does not show that advertisement it just displays the video while displaying the web application page.

Do we have any functionality of youtube where we can add `Ads` with `skip` functionality? Please help

Comment: can you share some demo code??

Comment: You able to do this? If yes, please let us know. Because i also want to do the same...

Answer (score 0):

Create an overlay for youtube iframe. Handle click event and start playing your custom advertisement. For skip functionality just add a Skip button in overlay and hide/remove overlay on click.

Also have a look at [youtube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: Will you please elaborate on this, or do you have a sample to achieve the same. Please let us know.